# Composition of Projection Maps

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

I am answering the question:

If $S,T$ are two projections, and $S∘T=T∘S$, show that $S∘T$ is a projection, and express its null space and range in terms of those of $S$ and $T$.

I have proven the first part; also, I have deduced that $N(S∘T) = R(T) \cap N(S)$. I am stuck on the last part, but I'm aware that clearly $R(S∘T)$ is equal to the range under S of $R(T)$. Is there an easier way to express this?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $v$ is a vector in $N(S\circ T)$. Then  $S\circ T(v)=0$, i.e. $S(T(v))=0$, and so $T(v)\in N(S) \cap R(T)$. Conversely any element $w$ in $N(S) \cap R(T)$ has the form $T(v)$ for some (not necessarily unique $v$) and this $v$ lies in $N(S\circ T)$

So we conclude that $$N(S\circ T)=T^{-1}(N(S) \cap R(T)),$$ the preimage of $N(S) \cap R(T)$ under $T$

Similarly, we have $$N(T\circ S)=S^{-1}(N(T) \cap R(S)).$$

Finally $R(S\circ T)$ is just the range of the projector $S$ restricted to $R(T)$ and you can guess the version for $T\cap S$.